# Accuracy not Increasing in fake news classifier

Tags: deep-learning, accuracy

I have been trying to build a fake news classifier DL model.
[Notebook here](https://github.com/tikendraw/fake_news_classifier/blob/main/fake_news_classifier.ipynb)

Problem is when i put the same data in a  `Multinomial` model it gives good accuracy.
But when coverted into tensors and fed to DL model accuracy lingers around 50% . I tried tweaking some parameters and watched the dataset again and again. I couldn't figure out. I may me missing something somewhere.

I would love to have you views on where I am making the mistake.
[Notebook here](https://github.com/tikendraw/fake_news_classifier/blob/main/fake_news_classifier.ipynb)

```
model1 = keras.Sequential()
model1.add(keras.Input(shape = (1), dtype = tf.string))
model1.add(title_text_vectorizer)
model1.add(title_embedder)
model1.add(layers.Conv1D(32, 5, 1, activation='relu'))
model1.add(layers.Dropout(.3))
model1.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model1.add(layers.Dense(1))

#compile
model1.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

fitting

```
hist1 = model1.fit(train_title_dataset, epochs = EPOCHS,
                      steps_per_epoch = int(.3* (len(train_title_dataset)/EPOCHS)),
                      validation_steps = int(.2* (len(train_title_dataset)/EPOCHS)),
                      validation_data=test_title_dataset,
                      callbacks = [create_tensorboard_callback('tb','model1')]
                    )
```

output

```
Saving TensorBoard log files to: tb/model1/20221110-212802
Epoch 1/10
17/17 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7065 - accuracy: 0.5051 - val_loss: 0.6983 - val_accuracy: 0.4963
Epoch 2/10
17/17 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7057 - accuracy: 0.5052 - val_loss: 0.6992 - val_accuracy: 0.4964
Epoch 3/10
17/17 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7062 - accuracy: 0.4980 - val_loss: 0.6973 - val_accuracy: 0.4970
Epoch 4/10
17/17 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7062 - accuracy: 0.4988 - val_loss: 0.6975 - val_accuracy: 0.4967
Epoch 5/10
17/17 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7042 - accuracy: 0.5010 - val_loss: 0.6965 - val_accuracy: 0.4998
Epoch 6/10
17/17 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7027 - accuracy: 0.5060 - val_loss: 0.7022 - val_accuracy: 0.4966
Epoch 7/10
17/17 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7009 - accuracy: 0.5165 - val_loss: 0.6993 - val_accuracy: 0.4961
Epoch 8/10
17/17 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.6997 - accuracy: 0.5158 - val_loss: 0.6971 - val_accuracy: 0.4965
Epoch 9/10
17/17 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.7032 - accuracy: 0.5011 - val_loss: 0.6959 - val_accuracy: 0.4997
Epoch 10/10
17/17 [==============================] - 0s 7ms/step - loss: 0.7043 - accuracy: 0.4999 - val_loss: 0.6973 - val_accuracy: 0.4966
```

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. If a simple model works well and a complex one doesn't, my first guess would be overfitting.

Comment: I am quite feeling welcomed. But please have a look if you can. Yell at my mistake. Please.

Comment: Had a very quick look, the first thing I would investigate is the NaN loss values during training. Apparently something goes wrong in the calculation of the loss, which could prevents the model from learning anything.

Comment: Thank you @Erwan. You have been helpful.